# Prerequisite condition for VC++ x86 runtime

Tags: installshield

I added VC++ 64 bit runtime prerequisite to my InstallShild project. File is downloaded from Microsoft page: https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe
and has the following description: **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.34.31931.**

When this file is executed, it creates/updates the following Registry entry:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\14.0\RuntimeMinimum`, `Version`, `14.34.31931`. Accordingly, I added the following Prerequisite Condition to InstallShield:

[image: x64 Prerequisite Condition]

Everything is OK for x64. Now I want to add VC++ x86 runtime to the same project. File `https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x86.exe`, description: **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x86) - 14.34.31931.**

When this file is executed, it creates/updates the following Registry entry:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\14.0\RuntimeMinimum`, `Version`, `14.34.31931`. I would like to make Prerequisite Condition by the same way, as for x64. But this doesn't work, because x64 installer actually creates two registry entries:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\14.0\RuntimeMinimum` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\14.0\RuntimeMinimum`, filling them by the same way. So, if x64 VC++ Runtime is already installed, x86 `WOW6432Node` condition doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem? The project has InstallScript type, so I can override installation events, if necessary. InstallShield version is 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following registry keys:

For 64-bit setup,

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\X64
Value: Version
```

For 32-bit setup,

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86
Value: Version
```

Condition type should be:

[image]

Comment: Indeed, this Registry entry is unique and not overridden by x64 version.